# Wordpress Woocommerce Advice with PHP code

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm working with the woo commerece plugin and i'd like to have a sub heading under the title of each product.
Style and format is sorted however i want a particular Category to show in the sub heading section. I've managed to get as far as showing all categories but i want to narrow this down to just one category that is under a parent category.
Below is the code i am using, could anyone suggest how i could achieve showing any child category selected under a parent category.
Thanks

```
<?php
/**
 * Single Product title
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

global $post, $product;

$cat_count = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) );
?>

<h1 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

<?php echo $product->get_categories( ', ', '<span class="posted_in">' . _n( 'Artist:', 'Artist:', $cat_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' ); ?>
```

---

This is what came out:

> Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 59 [name] => Colourful
>   [slug] => colourful [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 59
>   [taxonomy] => product_cat [description] => [parent] => 115 [count] =>
>   21 [filter] => raw ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 96 [name]
>   => Karen Grant [slug] => karen-grant [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 96 [taxonomy] => product_cat [description] =>
>   [parent] => 90 [count] => 5 [filter] => raw ) [2] => stdClass Object (
>   [term_id] => 69 [name] => Landscapes [slug] => landscapes [term_group]
>   => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 69 [taxonomy] => product_cat [description] => [parent] => 115 [count] => 35 [filter] => raw ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [term_id] => 71 [name] => Nature [slug] => nature
>   [term_group] => 0 [term_taxonomy_id] => 71 [taxonomy] => product_cat
>   [description] => [parent] => 115 [count] => 20 [filter] => raw ) )

```
<?php

/**
 * Single Product title
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     1.6.4
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly


global $post, $product;

$cat_count = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' ) );
?>


<h1 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

<?php 


    global $post, $product;

    $cat_array = array();
    $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat', array("fields" => "all")); //get array containing category details

    foreach($term_list as $cat_list)
    {

        array_push($cat_array, $cat_list->term_id);

    }

    $cat_id = ($term_list[0]->parent); //get parent category ID from the above generated array

   $termchildren = get_term_children( '90' , 'product_cat' ); //New Line in Updattion -1

   $final_result = array_intersect($cat_array,$termchildren); print_r($final_result);

    $new_cat_id = $final_result[0];

    $cat_url = get_term_link ($new_cat_id, 'product_cat'); //get link of parent ID

    $term = get_term( $new_cat_id, 'product_cat' ); //Get Name of the parent from the parent ID

    $name = $term->name; //Store it into an varialbe

    echo "Artist: <a href='".esc_url($cat_url)."'>".$name."</a>";
?>
```

'

Comment: I didn't get you.Can you please elaborate more ?

Comment: I have a products on my site and i'd like to add the artist of the product under the product title. I've done this but i want to display the artist name. Each artist is also a category, so i would like to display categories linked to this product however i have other categories linked to this. I would like to only allow the parent category of the artists to be displayed which would eliminate all other categories. The parent category is Artists, is there a way to say product category artists so that it doesn't display all categories only the child from artists.

Comment: I am still not getting it :) But what I got is, you want to have one name only below the title which is Artist.So if this is the case, I would suggest you to do with `custom field` and retrieve it.

Comment: Thats right but i want to pull this name from the category. The above code does this but pulls all categories linked to that product. Is there away to specifically state only pull categories under a parent category? instead of looking at all categories?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
<?php 

    global $post, $product;

    $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat', array("fields" => "all")); //get array containing category details

    $cat_id = ($term_list[0]->parent); //get parent category ID from the above generated array

    $cat_url = get_term_link ($cat_id, 'product_cat'); //get link of parent ID

    $term = get_term( $cat_id, 'product_cat' ); //Get Name of the parent from the parent ID

    $name = $term->name; //Store it into an varialbe

    echo "Artist: <a href='".esc_url($cat_url)."'>".$name."</a>";

?>
```

**Remember :**

In `WooCommerce`, products categories are not **normal categories**, they are a **custom taxonomy** created specifically for **products** which is just labeled as **"Categories"**.

Let me know If you have any doubt.

**Updated:**

```
    <?php 

        global $post, $product;

        $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat', array("fields" => "all")); //get array containing category details

        $cat_id = ($term_list[0]->parent); //get parent category ID from the above generated array

       $termchildren = get_term_children( '90' , 'product_cat' ); //New Line in Updattion -1

        $new_cat_id = $termchildren[2];

        $cat_url = get_term_link ($new_cat_id, 'product_cat'); //get link of parent ID

        $term = get_term( $new_cat_id, 'product_cat' ); //Get Name of the parent from the parent ID

        $name = $term->name; //Store it into an varialbe

        echo "Artist: <a href='".esc_url($cat_url)."'>".$name."</a>";

    ?>
```

**New Updated(02 January 2015)**

```
    <?php 

        global $post, $product;

        $cat_array = array();
        $term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat', array("fields" => "all")); //get array containing category details

        foreach($term_list as $cat_list)
        {

            array_push($cat_array, $cat_list->term_id);

        }

        $cat_id = ($term_list[0]->parent); //get parent category ID from the above generated array

       $termchildren = get_term_children( '90' , 'product_cat' ); //New Line in Updattion -1

       $final_result = array_intersect($cat_array,$termchildren);

       $final_cat_result = array_values($final_result);

        $new_cat_id = $final_cat_result[0];

        $cat_url = get_term_link ($new_cat_id, 'product_cat'); //get link of parent ID

        $term = get_term( $new_cat_id, 'product_cat' ); //Get Name of the parent from the parent ID

        $name = $term->name; //Store it into an varialbe

        echo "Artist: <a href='".esc_url($cat_url)."'>".$name."</a>";
    ?>
```

**Line : 1** `$post` and `$product` both are the **global variables**.So in term to use that in other files, we need to add that in our file before using it.

**Line : 2** One **blank array** to store all the categories of the current product**.We will use it in a future.

**Line : 3** [`wp_get_post_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms#Examples) is used to **retrieve the terms of the post**(for woocommerce its category for product).So now we have an array containing all the details of terms with `ID, name` etc etc

**Line : 4** It is for the loop through above generated array.We will loop through an array and look for `term_id`.We will use [`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) to store all the term ID and for storing we will use blank array from line 2.So now we have an array of `term_id`.

**Line : 9** Now we will use [`get_term_children`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_children#Examples) to retrieve the children term of **Artist** as we know the artist `term ID` and its fixed.It will give an **array** as an output.

**Line : 10** [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) is useful to match two array and fetch out only matching values.(Basically we are looking in to the current product category and all artist category to take out the matching category only).

**Line : 11** [`array_values`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) is useful to re-index the array.(By adding this line we solve the error that was coming :) )

**Line : 12** Now we have an array that is having only **one** value which is artist's `term ID`.(That's it.Now you need to fetch only name and link of the artist from that term ID)

**Line : 13** Fetch link of the artist.

**Line : 15** Fetch name of the artist from an array generated in line 14 and store it in variable.

**Line : 16** Print the needed thing and we are done !

Comment: Would it be easier for you to see the site? I can open access now. The product i am working off as an example is: https://www.artgiftedbygod.co.uk/online-art-shop/conceptual/repeated-11/

Comment: Those numbers generated seem to be the sub cats under the other parent cat

Comment: So you always want to use `artist`(whose ID is **90**) as the parent and then want to retrieve its child..right?

Comment: Yep. So basically the user sees the title which is the art work title and then under this the artist is listed, so they know who painted the work.

Comment: So if you manually add **90** `$termchildren = get_term_children( 90, 'product_cat' );` and then do `print_r($termchildren)` what is it giving? Do the change and let me know that generated array is having your ID that you want or not.

Comment: See my updated answer ..But I guess it will give correct artist name for that painting only.We need to change in coding for that.But I ll be off duty in 5 minute so I can help you tomorrow.Sorry ..I ll be available tomorrow at 10 IST.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I'll put the new code in and come back to you.

Comment: Yes you are correct, shows the correct artist for that painting and it shows that artist for all other paintings.

Comment: Hi sorry, i was away most of today. Any further ideas on how i can show the correct artist for each product? Thanks and Happy New Year

Comment: I wrote different code to pull out artist.Just let me know when you are online so that if there is some issue related to that code, we can sort it out.

Comment: Hi i'm online, i'll upload that code now and give it ago. thanks

Comment: Oh, sorry it said updated yesterday and i guessed it was changed. Thanks

Comment: Updated .. Let me know the output.. .

Comment: Its gone a bit crazy. Nothing is displaying but an error, however the array its pulling through 105 is the correct artist for this picture. Here is the error: Array ( [2] => 105 ) 
Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /homepages/38/d440545937/htdocs/Sites/ArtGiftedByGod/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 3043.

Comment: This is the page i'm working off: https://www.artgiftedbygod.co.uk/online-art-shop/botanical/pink-tulips/

Comment: So we are almost there :) It is getting the ID so now we need to solve that error only ..Let me have a look into this error ..

Comment: It might be todo with the page been a bit messy. I've cut old code out and added yours, basically all the stuff from woo commerce except the H1 title

Comment: Don't know, can you start to remove line from the last and see the output to check which line causing the error ?

Comment: Issue is in the last line of the code `echo "Artist: <a href='".esc_url($cat_url)."'>".$name."</a>";` .. If you comment it out then it wont give you an error ...I am working on it ..

Comment: I've tried to edit my original post to show the code i am putting on the page but it cuts it off. Which line do you want me to remove?

Comment: Just commented it out and now the array is showing as code but it is correct, 105 is the artist.

Comment: Try my today's updated answer again.I think now it should print the artist.

Comment: Perfect! its working. Thank you so much for all your help, this has really made a difference. Page with working code: https://www.artgiftedbygod.co.uk/online-art-shop/jane-brighton/dawn-2/

Comment: I owe your treat ;) You can accept the answer .. Happy New Year.And let me know if you want to understand the code.

Comment: I do want to understand it as my PHP knowledge is slowly growing but i dont want to trouble you.

Comment: Its okay dude ..I love to help people :) I will edit detailed answer in a while.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help. I have another question very closely linked to this that i will begin a new question on. Its basically the reverse of this. I'll add it now, not sure if its an easy fix as you've written this code which might answer the new question.

Comment: Okay ..post it as a new .. I ll look and I ll try to answer if I can.