# Wordpress - Woocommerce issue with custom code

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have had alot of help before from Rohil_PHPBeginner and the code he helped me with worked really well.

Today i have had someone on the site they removed a category that the code used needed to print the information i needed on screen.

The original code that solved my issues is found here:

[Wordpress Woocommerce Advice with PHP code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27712678/wordpress-woocommerce-advice-with-php-code#comment43855609_27720441)

Unfortunately the code is stopping my product page from displaying the product information. If i remove the code then it works fine but the functionality the code added really made the product page so much better.

I've checked and the category that was deleted was get_term_child, so i made sure to change this number on the product title.php

However nothing has worked and i get this error message (seen on this page)
https://www.artgiftedbygod.co.uk/online-art-shop/musical-paintings/marely/

Could anyone help me?

I've tried to fix the issue but i dont think it is related to this category being deleted as i have recreated it and changed the title.php to the correct number.

Thanks

Adam

Comment: I've had to take the code out of the product page so that it would work.

Comment: I have images of what it looked like when working and what it looks like now